# Creating an ipynb from URL

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

really simple question.

I have a URL [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/raw/master/doc/source/style.ipynb) that I'm trying to open in Jupyter lab as a jupyter notebook. What is the easiest way to do this? Is there a command line command somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

step 1:
visiting the URL "`ctrl + s`" to download that file (you would get the file name as **xxx.ipynb.txt**)

step 2:
Start `jupyter notebook`. Find the directory where you save to and double click file to open it.

step 3: Change it's name from **'xxx.ipynb.txt' to 'xxx.ipynb'**. (delete .txt in the last of file name)close the window and open it again.

I think it's work!!

Answer (score 0):

Just download that file to a working directory - with a menu 'save link as...' or visiting the URL and doing save.

Start `juypter notebook` from shell (commandline).

In the directory window that it opens for you, double click the saved `style.ipynb`.  Now you have the notebook running in a new window.